# Simple high-score update using binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
//#define DEBUG
int main()
{

#ifndef DEBUG
int new_highscore;
cout << "Enter your new highscore: ";
cin >> new_highscore; //input 5
#endif

fstream file("bin_file.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out); //file already had 10 6 4

#ifdef DEBUG
int x = 0;
while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x)))
cout << x << " ";
#endif

#ifndef DEBUG
if (file.is_open())
{
    streampos pre_pos = ios::beg;
    int cur_score = 0;
    vector <int> scores;

    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cur_score), sizeof(cur_score)))
    {
        if (cur_score < new_highscore)
        {
            break;
        }
        pre_pos = file.tellg();
    }

    if (file.fail() && !file.eof())
    {
        cout << "Error! Exiting..." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    file.clear();
    file.seekg(pre_pos);

    //get all scores that lesser than new high scores into vector
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cur_score), sizeof(cur_score)))
        scores.push_back(cur_score);

    //put new high score into right position 
    //edit
    file.seekp(pre_pos);
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&new_highscore), sizeof(new_highscore));

    //put all the scores that lesser than new high score into file
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = scores.begin(); it != scores.end(); it++)
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&*it), sizeof(*it));
    file.clear();
}
else
    cout << "Error openning file! " << endl;

//Try to print to console the result for checking
cout << "Review:" << endl;
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
int temp = 0;

while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(temp), sizeof (temp))) //Error here, and can't write 5 to the file
    cout << temp << endl;
#endif
file.close();
return 0;
}
```

code link: http://ideone.com/pC2ngX

So i tried to update from my already had binary file. But it couldn't get the new highscore and review it to me, please so me where is wrong and how to fix it, thanks !!
(I'm not English so sorry if my English isn't decent)

Comment: Unless you really need to do it this way it's much easier to read the whole file, add the new value(s) at the end of the vector, sort the vector, then write the whole thing back out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit is clearly wrong (assuming you actually want the values sorted):

```
//put new high score into last position in file
file.seekp(0, ios::end);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&new_highscore), sizeof(new_highscore));
```

as you are putting the value at the end, not at the position where you calculated the value should go (`pre_pos`).

This can be made simpler:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = scores.begin(); it != scores.end(); it++)
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&*it), sizeof(*it));
```

as:

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(scores.data()), sizeof(scores[0]) * scores.size());
```

Generally, I would just read the file into a vector, insert the new value in the right place in memory, and write it back out. The only situation where that may not work is if your high-score table is more than 2-3GB and your OS/App is 32-bit.